# How to supply URL to function requiring a filename in Python

Tags: python, url, arguments, filenames

I'm looking for a general recipe to use a URL for a function that expects a filename.  I've puzzled one out, but it's a little complex and easy to get wrong.

In this case, my function is `read_file` from `geopandas`, but it would be the same problem in any case.

```
import tempfile, requests
import geopandas as gpd

def as_file(url):
    tfile = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
    tfile.write(requests.get(url).content)
    return tfile

URL = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bowmanmc/ohiorepresents/master/data/congressional.min.json'
tf = as_file(URL)
gpd.read_file(tf.name)
```

That works, and doesn't look too awful, but I had to experiment a bunch to find it, because slight variants raise `OSError: no such file or directory`, due to the lifespan of tempfiles; yet I also don't want to clutter the filesystem with permanent files.

This fails:

```
def as_file(url):
    tfile = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
    tfile.write(requests.get(url).content)
    return tfile.name

gpd.read_file(as_file(URL))
```

and even this:

```
def as_file(url):
    tfile = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
    tfile.write(requests.get(url).content)
    return tfile

gpd.read_file(as_file(URL).name)
```

Is there a more obvious, memorable, or bulletproof way?

Comment: You could use [`contextlib.contextmanager`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager), and `with`. Sorry no time to provide a better answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a context manager to manage the lifetime of the temporary file:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def as_file(url):
    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as tfile:
        tfile.write(requests.get(url).content)
        tfile.flush()
        yield tfile.name
```

Note: The `with NamedTemporaryFile() as tfile` will only work with Python 3. Otherwise you'll have to make sure it cleans up properly yourself for Python 2.

Usage:

```
with as_file(URL) as filename:
    gpd.read_file(filename)
```

Comment: That's it, thank you!  Actually, it seems to work without the `tfile.flush()` as well.

Comment: If too few bytes are written, the buffer might not flush, and geopandas will try reading empty or partial data from the file. Try replacing `requests.get(url).content` with `'hello'` and see what `gpd.read_file` gets.